# Are all dependencies recommended by angular2 quickstart really necessary?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am new to angular2 and I have never used angular1.

I have been trying this tutorial https://angular.io/guide/quickstart and
i wonder if all the recommended dependencies are really necessary because my project size gets big after 'npm install' (more than 100Mb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't necessarily use all of the @angular dependencies during the Quickstart, but if you continue on with their tutorial and as your app gets more complex, you will definitely utilize them.

The other packages are necessary. They consist of typescript compilers, libraries for Observables, and more Angular 2 features. [Here](https://daveceddia.com/angular-2-dependencies-overview/) is a quick read for  info on some of these.

If you're using `angular-cli`, calling `ng serve` will also run a series of automated tests that depend on packages.